# Elasticsearch + Spark: write json with custom document _id

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-hadoop

I am trying to write a collection of objects in Elasticsearch from Spark. I have to meet two requirements:

1. Document is already serialized in JSON and should be written as is
2. Elasticsearch document `_id` should be provided

Here's what I tried so far.

#### `saveJsonToEs()`

I tried to use [`saveJsonToEs()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/5.6/spark.html#spark-streaming-write-json) like this (the serialized document contains field `_id` with desired Elasticsearch ID):

```
val rdd: RDD[String] = job.map{ r => r.toJson() }

val cfg = Map(
  ("es.resource", "myindex/mytype"),
  ("es.mapping.id", "_id"),
  ("es.mapping.exclude", "_id")
)

EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(rdd, cfg)
```

But the [`elasticsearch-hadoop`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop) library gives this exception:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: When writing data as JSON, the field exclusion feature is ignored. This is most likely not what the user intended. Bailing out...
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.validateSettings(InitializationUtils.java:253)
```

If I remove `es.mapping.exclude` but keep `es.mapping.id` and send a JSON with `_id` inside (like `{"_id":"blah",...}`)

```
val cfg = Map(
  ("es.resource", "myindex/mytype"),
  ("es.mapping.id", "_id")
)

EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(rdd, cfg)
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 15 in stage 84.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 15.3 in stage 84.0 (TID 628, 172.31.35.69, executor 1): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Found unrecoverable error [172.31.30.184:9200] returned Bad Request(400) - Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters.; Bailing out..
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
...
```

When I try to send this id as a different field (like `{"superID":"blah",..."`:

```
 val cfg = Map(
  ("es.resource", "myindex/mytype"),
  ("es.mapping.id", "superID")
)

EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(rdd, cfg)
```

It fails to extract the field:

```
17/12/20 15:15:38 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.0 in stage 84.0 (TID 586, 172.31.33.56, executor 0): org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: [JsonExtractor for field [superId]] cannot extract value from entity [class java.lang.String] | instance [{...,"superID":"7f48c8ee6a8a"}]
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.bulk.AbstractBulkFactory$FieldWriter.write(AbstractBulkFactory.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.bulk.TemplatedBulk.writeTemplate(TemplatedBulk.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.bulk.TemplatedBulk.write(TemplatedBulk.java:56)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.writeToIndex(RestRepository.java:161)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:67)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$doSaveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:107)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$doSaveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
```

When I remove `es.mapping.id` and `es.mapping.exclude` from the configuration, it works but the document id is generated by Elasticsearch (which violates requirement 2):

```
val rdd: RDD[String] = job.map{ r => r.toJson() }

val cfg = Map(
  ("es.resource", "myindex/mytype"),
)

EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(rdd, cfg)
```

#### `saveToEsWithMeta()`

There is another function to provide `_id` and other [metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_document_metadata.html) for inserting: [`saveToEsWithMeta()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/5.6/spark.html#spark-streaming-write-meta) that allows to solve requirement 2 but fails with requirement 1.

```
val rdd: RDD[(String, String)] = job.map{
  r => r._id -> r.toJson()
}

val cfg = Map(
  ("es.resource", "myindex/mytype"),
)

EsSpark.saveToEsWithMeta(rdd, cfg)
```

In fact, Elasticsearch is not even able to parse what the `elasticsearch-hadoop` sends:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Found unrecoverable error [<es_host>:9200] returned Bad Request(400) - failed to parse; Bailing out..
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
```

#### The question

Is it possible to write a collection of `(documentID, serializedDocument)` from Spark into Elasticsearch (using `elasticsearch-hadoop`)?

P.S. I am using Elasticsearch 5.6.3 and Spark 2.1.1.

Comment: Have you tried keeping the `es.mapping.id` setting while removing the `es.mapping.exclude`? Honestly I don't even get why would you need exclusion at all

Comment: @AlexSavitsky Thanks for the note, I updated the question! It still does not work though :(

Comment: The reason I suggested trying this is that I had a similar use case recently, only my data was CSV with an explicitly defined schema. My ID column was part of the schema, it was also specified in `es.mapping.id`, and it was saved to ES with no issues. I assumed this would work the same for JSON data, but apparently this is not the case.

Answer (score 6):

Finally I found the problem: it was a typo in the config.

```
[JsonExtractor for field [superId]] cannot extract value from entity [class java.lang.String] | instance [{...,"superID":"7f48c8ee6a8a"}]
```

It was looking for a field `superID` but there was only `superID` (note the case). In the question it is also a bit misleading since in the code it appears like `"es.mapping.id", "superID"` (which was not correct).

The actual solution is like [Levi Ramsey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47913698/5095957) suggested:

```
val json = """{"foo":"bar","superID":"deadbeef"}"""

val rdd = spark.makeRDD(Seq(json))
val cfg = Map(
  ("es.mapping.id", "superID"),
  ("es.resource", "myindex/mytype")
)
EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(rdd, cfg = cfg)
```

The difference is that `es.mapping.id` cannot be `_id` (as was indicated in the original post, `_id` is the metadata and Elasticsearch does not accept it).

Naturally it means that the new field `superID` should be added to the mapping (unless the mapping is dynamic). If storing additional field in the index is a burden, one should also:

- [exclude](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping-source-field.html#include-exclude) it from the mapping
- and disable its indexing

Thanks a lot to [Alex Savitsky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892705/elasticsearch-spark-write-json-with-custom-document-id?noredirect=1#comment82754053_47892705) for pointing to the correct direction.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like:

```
val rdd: RDD[String] = job.map{ r => r.toJson() }
val cfg = Map(
  ("es.mapping.id", "_id")
)
rdd.saveJsonToEs("myindex/mytype", cfg)
```

I've tested (with elasticsearch-hadoop (connector version 2.4.5) against ES 1.7) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by passing `ES_INPUT_JSON` option to `cfg`
 parameters map and returning a tuple containing the document id as the first element and the document serialized in JSON as the second element from the map function.

I tested it with `"org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark-20" % "[6.0,7.0["` against Elasticsearch 6.4

```scala
import org.elasticsearch.hadoop.cfg.ConfigurationOptions.{ES_INPUT_JSON, ES_NODES}
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._

job
  .map{ r => (r._id, r.toJson()) }
  .saveToEsWithMeta(
    "myindex/mytype",
    Map(
      ES_NODES -> "https://localhost:9200",
      ES_INPUT_JSON -> true.toString
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent days banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why `saveToEsWithMeta` would not work when I used a string for the ID like so:

```
rdd.map(caseClassContainingJson =>
  (caseClassContainingJson._idWhichIsAString, caseClassContainingJson.jsonString)
)
.saveToEsWithMeta(s"$nationalShapeIndexName/$nationalShapeIndexType", Map(
  ES_INPUT_JSON -> true.toString
))
```

This will throw JSON parsing-related errors, which deceptively leads you towards thinking that the issue is with your JSON, but then you log each one of your JSONs and see they're all valid.

Turns out that for whatever reason `ES_INPUT_JSON -> true` makes the left-hand side of the tuple, i.e. the ID, get parsed as a JSON too!

the solution, JSON stringify the ID (will wrap ID in extra double quotes) so that parsing it as a JSON works:

```
rdd.map(caseClassContainingJson =>
  (
    Json.stringify(JsString(caseClassContainingJson._idWhichIsAString)), 
    caseClassContainingJson.jsonString
  )
)
.saveToEsWithMeta(s"$nationalShapeIndexName/$nationalShapeIndexType", Map(
  ES_INPUT_JSON -> true.toString
))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use `saveToEs` in order to define customer_id and do not have to save customer_id
2. note the rdd is `RDD[Map]` type

```
val rdd:RDD[Map[String, Any]]=...
val cfg = Map(
  ("es.mapping.id", your_customer_id),
  ("es.mapping.exclude", your_customer_id)
)
EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, your_es_index, cfg)
```